# Get current Content-Type header in PHP

Tags: php, logging, http-headers

I'm running a PHP script to log all requests to my site in a MySQL database. Some scripts on my site also modify the `Content-Type` header using `header("Content-Type: image/png");` to output images, for instance. I'm trying to log this Content-Type, too. How can I get a string variable containing the Content-Type?

Comment: What does your script look like? When is it fired? If it is fired at the end of every script, you can check the currently set headers using php function headers-list http://de1.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php

Comment: This is good. Post it as an answer and I'll vote it up.

Comment: I gave it an edit. I think now it deserves to be accepted right? 
;-)

Comment: Of course, but I'm just checking it out first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What does your script look like? When is it executed?
If it is executed at the end of every script, you can check the currently set headers using [php function headers-list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php)

Here is an easy example of how to use it:

```
<?php
// headers sent
$headers = headers_list(); // get list of headers
foreach ($headers as $header) { // iterate over that list of headers
  if(stripos($header,'Content-Type') !== FALSE) { // if the current header hasthe String "Content-Type" in it
    $headerParts = explode(':',$header); // split the string, getting an array
    $headerValue = trim($headerParts[1]); // take second part as value
    $yourLoggingService->setContentTypeOfCurrentCall($headerValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: There's an error in the `if` statement: `>=0` always returns true for `stripos`checks. Use `!== false` instead and this works like a charm.

Comment: @Rapti sorry, my fault. fixed it.